# Gtk Granite : About Dialog not appearing properly

Tags: vala

For some reason, the Gtk About Dialog is not appearing properly. My class is a subclass of Granite.Application. The About dialog which comes as part of the elementary desktop is also with the same problematic appearance. I have not been able to produce this with a MVCE yet.

I have attached a screen shots of how the icon and the about dialog is appearing. After I do the build from source the icon and the about come properly. However, after installing from a Launchpad PPA it comes up with the incorrect looking About.

Appreciate any help on this.

The code is on GitHub here:
https://github.com/babluboy/bookworm/blob/master/src/bookworm.vala

Appreciate any help on resolving this.

[image]

Comment: any suggestions on what can be causing this?

Comment: This was due to a problem with Granite and has been resolved now

Comment: Please add the solution that solved your problem as **answer** bellow and mark it as one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrading to granite0.5 has solved the issue.